# image slideshow with control

Tags: javascript, css

can anyone help with creating an image slideshow with controls and also flips automatically. I've tried working it but none of the images showed till I clicked a button, It has been really frustrating

Answer (score 0):

The following link may be useful in helping to create a slideshow with both control and automatic flipping:

[How To Create a Slideshow](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)